# F measure using ROCR pckg in R

Tags: r, performance, logistic-regression, measure, auc

Deal all,

I'm working on a logistic regression model to classify a dataset in to 2 classes. I'm using the ROCR package, and I want to calculate the f-measure. My code is down there, but it gives me a vector not a single answer as the AUC or Accuracy.

```
p = predict(model, testData, type="response")
pr = prediction(p, testData$target)  
fmeasure = performance(pr,"f")
fmeasure = fmeasure@y.values[[1]]
```

where "model" is the logistic regression model.

Answer (score 0):

change this line ,  fmeasure = performance(pr,"f") to fmeasure  = performance(pr,"auc")

```
p = predict(model, testData, type="response")
pr = prediction(p, testData$target)  
fmeasure = performance(pr,"auc")
fmeasure = fmeasure@y.values[[1]]
```